# Get list of files in directory on server iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, nsfilemanager

I am trying to get a list of the available files when from a server and be able to look at the names of the files that are available. I was looking at using the NSFileManager, but it does not seem to want to return any results when I enter a URL. I basically want it to return something like when you type "ls" into bash/terminal

Can someone lend an example of how the contentsOfDirectoryAtURL method works and what arguments I should be putting to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSFileManager only works with local urls with scheme file:

How you talk to a server to access its contents depends on what protocol the server speaks.

Comment: The server is accessed normally over afp